# Consulta filtros dinamicos pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Una consulta

Necesito hacer un sp que recibe por parametros tres string que son utilizados para filtrar en el where

La duda que tengo es que puede venir uno solo con datos y los otros dos vacios como los tres con datos

Lo que se me habia ocurrido es hacer un string e ir concatenando depndiendo si la variable que recibe por parametro esta vacia o no

Hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

Por ejemplo si var1 = "prueba", var2 ="", var3 =""
En el where solo debe ir var1

En cambio si los tres tienen datos los tres deberian ir.
Puede darse el caso que var2 tenga datos y los otros dos no, como que var3 tenga datos ylos otros no o var2 y var3 tenga datos

Muchas gracias

Saludos

Comment: Depende netamente del manejo de tus datos, en este caso si necesitas filtrar en algún momento que ese valor igual fuese vacío o nulo puedes construir el string con esos valores, si no lo necesitas en la misma construcción lo puedes realizar. Ahora, esta validación la haces en un SP o la haces a través del backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Habrá muchas maneras de realizar esto. De momento te sugiero que hagas tu consulta dinámica en una variable `varchar`, y luego la ejecutes por medio de `execute immediate`. (Te sugiero investigar más acerca de `execute immediate` y busques ejemplos)

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P1
(
   Var1 IN VARCHAR2,
   Var2 IN VARCHAR2,
   Var3 IN varchar2
)
AS

dynaQuery VARCHAR2(8000);

BEGIN

dynaQuery := 'update table set column1 ='''valor''' where ';

IF var1 <> '' THEN

   dynaQuery := dynaQuery || ' var1 =  '''' || var1 || '''' And '   ;

ENDIF

/* hacer lo mismo con las otras 3 variables*/
/* no olvides borrar el último and */

/*Este comando ejecuta el query dinámico*/
execute immediate dynaQuery;
```